# .Net Add Index to Datatable (dataset)

Tags: c#, vb.net, dataset

Is there a way to add an index to a datatable in .Net?

I have a datatable holding about 1,100 rows and the datatable.select statement seems a bit slow for an in-memory operation.

Comment: [Scaling ADO.NET DataTables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364983.aspx).  There may be alternate ways, but with so little detail...

Comment: it is already following zero-based indexing. `.Rows[n]` will give you `nth` row

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[]{table.Columns["column1"],table.Columns["column2"]}
```

when searching

```
table.Rows.Find(New Object[]{<value in column1>, <value in column2>})
```

This will return a datarow. Also the Primary key values must be unique, otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Comment: This ia a great hint. For everybody reading after me: the correct syntax in line 1 is: `... new DataColumn[]{table.Columns( ...` Note the square brackets.

Comment: You should be able to leave `DataColumn` out of that and just use `new[] { table.Columns(...`

Comment: The correct syntax is table.Columns["column1"], not table.Columns("column1").

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Basic:

```
Dim table As New DataTable()

table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("MyColumn"))

Dim primaryKey(1) As DataColumn
primaryKey(1) = table.Columns("MyColumn")
table.PrimaryKey = primaryKey
```