# C# SQL Data adapter inserting rows in wrong order. DataAdapter.Update()

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dataset, dataadapter

The `dataadapter.Update()` method in C# is inserting the rows in SQL server database in wrong order.
I tried debugging the code. Following is the data in `dataset` table just before executing the `dataadapter.Update()` method.

```
 |JobID|Comment number|type|data|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 1            | 3  | XYZ|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 2            | 1  | ABC|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 3            | 5  | MNO|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 4            | 2  | PQR|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
```

But after execution of the `dataadapter.Update()` data stored in database is

```
 |JobID|Comment number|type|data|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 1            | 3  | XYZ|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 4            | 2  | PQR|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 2            | 1  | ABC|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 3            | 5  | MNO|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
```

I have tried to debug the code but could not find anything that is causing this change in order of the insertion.
Also looked it over the internet but no luck with that as well.

```
foreach (string s in tables)
{   
   trace.WriteFile("WriteToDb-19-" +s);
   da=CreateAdapter(s,conn,tran,ref errorCtrl);
   trace.WriteFile("WriteToDb-20-" +s);
   da.Update(ds.Tables[s]);
   trace.WriteFile("WriteToDb-21-" +s);
}
```

Actual data stored in DB should be:

```
 |JobID|Comment number|type|data|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 1            | 3  | XYZ|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 2            | 1  | ABC|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 3            | 5  | MNO|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 4            | 2  | PQR|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
```

instead of

```
 |JobID|Comment number|type|data|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 1            | 3  | XYZ|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 4            | 2  | PQR|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 2            | 1  | ABC|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
 |123  | 3            | 5  | MNO|
_|_____|______________|____|____|
```

Comment: From a database perspective, records aren't normally inserted in any particular order. And you shouldn't care what order they were inserted, when you query them you use an `order by` clause to obtain them in the desired order.

Comment: I think the data is still in correct order......and maybe its sorted on basis of JOBID ...you won't know unless you insert another JOBID and check the order

Comment: According to the docs the order of update is determined by the indexes configured on the DataSet (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.update?view=netframework-4.7.2) - have you configured your indexes?

Comment: @DaleBurrell I have checked there is no indexes configured on dataset. Also this is as existing application and I don't thing it will be possible to modify all the sql queries and use order by.

Comment: Based on the docs I posted all you have to do is create an index on your DataSet to have it insert  in the order you desire.

Comment: As previous comments have stated, the order does not matter. SQL has its own internal stuff going on that you need not worry about. When you query the data you can order it however you like. But I do notice something strange in you data though, the comment number and type combinations from before the insert differs from after the insert. This has nothing to do with order but indicates something is corrupting your data. This should be your real concern here.

Comment: @AndréEngelbrecht thanks for pointing that out but the data shown is hypothetical. And I have made the correction.

Comment: @DaleBurrell can you please suggest how I can create index on DataSet? Is there any function that I can use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016084/net-add-index-to-datatable-dataset